# How do I make a unique temporary file to be made for each visitor and store other file pathnames

Tags: php, mysql, temp

Basically I am aware that you can make temporary file (lets call it file2) with the tempnam function in PHP. However, i was wondering how they could automatically be deleted when the user leaves the site. Or even better have that temp file be stored for that user and identified through a cookie.

I manually made a blank text file on which when a user drags an item into a basket that specific pathname for the item is added to the text file however, how do i make this occur for a temporary file which is automatically created when the unique user enters the site. I have a basic template on the site to help grasp your heads around the idea. However, of cource its not functioning properly at the moment as I have left some parts out.

Comment: Use sessions, and delete the file when the session expires. Sessions are (typically) associated to users by a cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not sessions?

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['basket'] = "Whatever you like";
```

[php.net/Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)